# Set vertical Index for dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to bring the index 'Stkcd' into vertical index so that it will show a row of 1,2,3 .... for each row. I have try many transpose with different index but I seem that the index always shifting to the horizontal row, which is not what I want. I want my result to be like this.[Stkcd on the vertical index on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlatB.png)

This is what I am getting [I don't want the Stkcd to be on the horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hC4y.png) And the original data is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke0Xt.png)

Comment: Looks like you want to transpose and then group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unstack`:

Given:

```
print(df1)
                  value
Stkcd date             
1     2015-12-02     11
      2015-12-03     12
      2015-12-04     12
      2015-12-05     11
      2015-12-06     10
      2015-12-07     12
      2015-12-08     10
      2015-12-09     10
      2015-12-10     11
      2015-12-11     14
      2015-12-12     14
      2015-12-13     12
      2015-12-14     14
2     2015-12-02     13
      2015-12-03     14
      2015-12-04     10
      2015-12-05     12
      2015-12-06     13
      2015-12-07     12
      2015-12-08     11
      2015-12-09     10
      2015-12-10     12
      2015-12-11     12
      2015-12-12     13
      2015-12-13     10
      2015-12-14     11
3     2015-12-02     10
      2015-12-03     11
      2015-12-04     13
      2015-12-05     11
      2015-12-06     12
      2015-12-07     10
      2015-12-08     12
      2015-12-09     11
      2015-12-10     14
      2015-12-11     13
      2015-12-12     12
      2015-12-13     11
      2015-12-14     12

df1.unstack()
```

Output:

```
           value                                                                               \
date  2015-12-02 2015-12-03 2015-12-04 2015-12-05 2015-12-06 2015-12-07 2015-12-08 2015-12-09   
Stkcd                                                                                           
1             11         12         12         11         10         12         10         10   
2             13         14         10         12         13         12         11         10   
3             10         11         13         11         12         10         12         11   


date  2015-12-10 2015-12-11 2015-12-12 2015-12-13 2015-12-14  
Stkcd                                                         
1             11         14         14         12         14  
2             12         12         13         10         11  
3             14         13         12         11         12
```